# Divide result of one query on result of another query

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 3 columns (name, course, grade).
My 'name' column contains three students.
I need to sum grades of every student and divide it by the amount of grades.

I'm trying to do something like this,

```
    SELECT 
        name 
    FROM 
        table 
    GROUP BY 
        name 
    AND 
        (SELECT SUM(grade) FROM table / SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM table GROUP BY name)
```

I'm not a native english speaker, so I hope you understand me.

Comment: You want to calculate the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you want to calculate the average grade?

```
SELECT name, AVG(grade)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Forgot how to say it in english. Thank you, your decision helped me.

Answer (score 0):

your table design does not follow the 1st rule of normalization: atomicity. You have multiple names in single column AND you want to process them separately. This makes querying more difficult and inefficient. You need to normalize your table.

Comment: I know that, actually I was thinking about that design from the beginning but unfortunately this is a task that was given to me, so I can't change anything in table. I'm not very good in mysql, so that's why I'm asking for help of Internet-society.